# I have a MSDN windows 7 Key, but cant find the Media for it. I need specific Windows 7 MSDN Ultimate can someone provide me a link please?

Tags: windows-7, windows, msdn

I have a MSDN windows 7 Key, but cant find the Media for it. I need specific Windows 7 MSDN Ultimate can someone provide me a link please?  I dont know where to find it from

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has an official site where you can enter your key and download the right ISO. This does not work for OEM versions (it asks you to contact the computer manufacturer). Usually you only need the right version to install, that means:

1. 32 or 64 bit
2. SP0 or SP1
3. Home / Professional or Ultimate

Link to [Microsoft download site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery)

Link to [the same question you had on Microsoft site](http://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/wo-kann-ich-die-windows-7-iso-dateien/610a3a3c-e99c-42e6-8cf8-fda31127b035?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MSDN key then to use it *you* need a valid MSDN subscription.  You can then login to the [msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) and download the correct ISO.